# Upload .xslx file to Document library in Office 365

Tags: office365

I upload a xml file and assign a custom document content to it. It works fine.
But with same code i uplaod a xlsx file and assign custom document content type. But when i view it Content type, it was set to default document.

When I upload same xlsx file through browser and assign custom document content type. It works fine.

And does Client Object Model provides any method to upload file In Office 365??

Answer (score 0):

Noramlly you can use sandbox method to deal with.

Comment: i try that but was unable to pass large size file ...if u have any idea how to do it?? Plz suggest